# Writing a program and need some input

Tags: python

I am doing a program about creating a file about golf, it allows only one For. When I run the program I get an error about Golf_File.write(Name + ("\n") ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
Num_People = int(input("How many golfers are playing?: "))
Golf_File = open('golf.txt', 'w')

for count in range(1,Num_People+1):
    Name = input("Enter the player's name: ")
    Score = int(input("Enter the player's score: "))
    Golf_File.write(Name + ("\n"))
    Golf_File.write(str(Score) + ("\n"))

    Golf_File.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```
Num_People = int(input("How many golfers are playing?: "))
Golf_File = open('golf.txt', 'w')

for count in range(1,Num_People+1):
    Name = input("Enter the player's name: ")
    Score = int(input("Enter the player's score: "))
    Golf_File.write(Name + ("\n"))
    Golf_File.write(str(Score) + ("\n"))

Golf_File.close()
```

The file should be closed outside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

It is generally considered better to use `with` statements to handle file objects

```py
Num_People = int(input("How many golfers are playing?: "))

with open('golf.txt', 'w') as Golf_File:
    for count in range(1,Num_People+1):
        Name = input("Enter the player's name: ")
        Score = int(input("Enter the player's score: "))
        Golf_File.write(Name + ("\n"))
        Golf_File.write(str(Score) + ("\n"))
```

You can read more about this in the Python documentation about [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

---

Also obligatory reminder about the official [Python naming standards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), capitalized variable names should be avoided